Seeking clarification or options for Snoutband
I understand Snoutband refers to a person who often interrupts a conversation to correct and/or contradict the speaker. Could it also refer to a person who butts in AND has to out do the person speaking?
For instance, when talking about fishing, a person might mention they caught an 8 lb. bass. The buttinsky would say, I caught a 9 lb. one.
If Snoutband is not appropriate, is there a term for such a person?

Never heard of snoutband before. You mean a word for a person who butts in? You've it right there in your question.

Snoutband isn't in Merriam-Webster, Wiktionary, or Cambridge dictionaries. I think it's a made up word, either the OP having a joke at us or someone having a joke at their expense. But the question could be rewritten without it.

@StuartF It's reported by WaPo, though I'm not sure the quality of their reporting here.

Like others, I have never before encountered snoutband. That it may sometimes be used by certain speakers or writers is one thing. But if you wish to be reliably understood, then I would suggest expressing yourself in other ways.

Google Ngrams has no record of this word. I guess it's a very recent coinage and hasn't made it into much recorded writing.

Snoutband comes from the Old English. This article has a number of links: https://profanitees.co.uk/snoutband/snoutband/.  I understand the meaning as stated. I was hoping for further clarification, specifically, if the term would also include a person who always butts in AND has to add something that they did and make it better or more impressive. I did provide an example.
